# Studying the equation $\ln(x)- 1+ x^2=0$

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

Can the equation $\ln(x)- 1 + x^2=0$ be solved without the Lambert $W$ function ? (I didn't study Lambert W yet).

By inspection I can see that $x=1$ is a solution. Are there other solutions? And is there a systematic way to find them?

Comment: You can't solve it analytically without using Lambert W, but it's pretty easy to spot that $x=1$. For a proof that this is the only solution, compute the derivative.

Comment: Are you looking for real or complex roots?

Comment: lambert W function is a multivalued function. The branch point of a multi-valued function is a point such that the function is discontinuous when going around an arbitrarily small circuit around this point?

Comment: Yeah I know that X=1 by inspection,but can it be proved mathematically?

Comment: I am looking for real roots.

Answer (score 5):

The function $f(x):=\ln x-1+x^2$ on $x>0$ satisfies $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=-\infty,\,\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $f^\prime=\frac1x+2x>0$, so the root on $\Bbb R^+$ is unique. By inspection, it's $x=1$.

<s>Edit, since the function whose roots are sought has been changed to $g(x):=\ln x+1-x^2$: it's unclear the root $\ne1$ can be obtained analytically without Lambert $W$, but you could numerically approximate it, e.g. with Newton-Raphson viz.$$x_0=\frac12,\,x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{\ln x_n+1-x_n^2}{1/x_n-2x_n}.$$</s>[Reverted]

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but can it be proved in a mathematical way?

Comment: @JonathanGamal [You seem to be mistaken](https://www.google.com/search?q=ln(0.450763652)-1%2B0.450763652%5E2&pws=0).

Comment: I have a mistake  the correct equation is Ln(X) +1 -X^2 =0

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: We are looking at is $\ln(x)\color{red}+1\color{red}-x^2$ EDIT: Oh, this is due to the OP changing the question

Comment: @JonathanGamal Why don't you open a new question and leave this one as is? What you have done renders this answer currently useless

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Okay I did that, thanks.

Comment: @JonathanGamal Oh I see now... You should revert this question back to the old version and I will vote to reopen the new one

Comment: And now it's considered as duplicate so it's closed . And this one isn't deleted. Please vote to delete it.

Comment: @JonathanGamal I suggest we should vote to reopen the other question after editing accrodingly and to keep this one as it was originally. Why do you want to delete it? That would also delete this answer...

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Done 

Comment: @JonathanGamal What do you mean by "done"? Your last edit undid my suggestion, which is to revert this question to the original state $\ln(x)-1+x^2$ and to reopen the other question concerning $\ln(x)+1-x^2$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch The original state of this question was ln(x) -1 +x^2

Comment: @JonathanGamal Exactly, and I want to restore that