# How to solve $\ln{x}+1−x^2=0$?

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

Can the equation $\ln(x)+ 1- x^2=0$ be solved without the Lambert W function ? (I didn't study Lambert W yet).

By inspection I can see that $x=1$ is a solution. Are there other solutions? And is there a systematic way to find them?

Note: I asked [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633136/) concerning $\ln(x)-1+x^2$, however, the answer there cannot be used for the function here.

Comment: Why do you post one question twice?

Comment: I made a mistake in the other question and when i edited it no-one saw it again. I tried to delete it but it didn't.

Comment: By inspection you find $x=1$ and $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x>0$, which means that $f(x)$ is intersecting the y-axis only once.

Comment: I am voting to reopen because OP first asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633136/), then changed that question and uploaded this question, which is identical to the edit. But the original question has been restored so this is no longer a duplicate

Comment: I've also voted to re-open for @MaximilianJanisch's reason.

Comment: To your question:  The function $f(x)=\ln (x) +1-x^2$ has derivative $\frac 1x -2x$ which has a single root at $x=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$ (since we require $x>0$).  The derivative is positive for $x$ below the root and negative above.  We see then that there are two solutions to your equation, one at $x=1$ as you have seen and another between $0$ and $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$  Newton's method, or whatever numerical scheme you prefer, shows that the non-trivial root is around $.450764$

Comment: @lulu Thanks, I know that it can be inspected easily, but can you prove it mathematically please?